# How to make a Unity Scroll Rect NOT overflow?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui, scrollrect

I have a scroll rect that has input fields in it, and I would like it so that the user only sees things that are currently in it. Right now it is overflowing and has everything in it going out below it. I would like it so that these bottom fields do not show until the user scrolls down, the only thing in view should be what is currently[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a mask component with your `Scroll Rect` holding object. Either `Rect Mask 2D` or `Mask`.

[image]

Comment: It works thank you so much! Also, for anyone else who has this problem in the future, the gameobject with the mask also needs an image on it

Comment: With RectMask2D you don't need an extra image.

Comment: Yes use RectMask2D, it has much better performance and should be the default option for 2D ui